# How to automatically update a pandas dataframe given an external website condition?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the target website: https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news?page=0

I create a python function to scrape all the informations from the news page and store everything inside a pandas data frame, like this:

```
def scrape_global_news(url):            
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    frame=[]
    filename="global_mobi_health_news.xlxs"
    f=open(filename,"w", encoding = 'utf-8')

    for row in soup.select('.group-left .views-row'):
        Region = "Global"
        Title = row.select_one('.views-field-title').get_text(strip=True)
        Content = row.select_one('.views-field-body').get_text(strip=True)
        Link = 'https://www.mobihealthnews.com' + row.a['href']
        Date = row.select_one('.day_list').get_text(strip=True)
        Author = row.select_one('.author_list').get_text(strip=True)
        frame.append((Region,Title,Content,Date,Link,Author))
        f.write(Title.replace(",","^")+","+Link+","+Author.replace(",","^")+","+Content.replace(",","^")+","+Date.replace(",","^")+"\n")
    f.close()
    df_global=pd.DataFrame(frame, columns=['Region','Title','Summarized Content','Creation Date','Source','Author Name'])
    return df_global
scrape_global_news('https://www.mobihealthnews.com/news?page=0')
```

In the image below there is the final result:

[image: df with all the scraped informations]

Now, I got two main problems:

1. To add and to implement a feature in order to check if inside the webpage above there's a new article (i.e. `df_global.Title[0] =! Title ]` and, if this condition is true, add the new article with the function `scrape_global_news` in the first dataframe's row.
2. Make this script automatically runs every 24 hours and deploy it inside cloud services providers (?). About this point, I'm not quite sure that proper cloud service is needed.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: To better explain #1 problem:

When I posted the question yesterday (07/21/2020), the first row was the latest article within the website linked above (i.e. the most recent one). If you check the website today, there are 4 more brand news articles on the top (this number is likely to increase with each passing day). I would like to fetch information from the 4 new articles within the website (with "scrape_global_news" function) and store them on the top of the data frame. The ultimate scope is to order them from the most recent to the last recent article

Comment: Instead of storing in local, write to a database

Comment: @bigbounty thank you. Can you please eleborate a bit your answer? What do you mean with "to a database"?

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer, that's better. As a heads up, insert into a database like mysql where data will be persisted

Comment: @bigbounty Thank you, also I am still trying to figure out a way to constantly update the df with python (i.e. add new rows to the top when new articles are pushed within the website)

Comment: DataFrame will be in memory. You need to hold the data for longer periods of time. Local Filesystem won't scale. Hence, use a database like mysql. If you want the data, you can query mysql

Comment: Totally agree with you. Since I can't actually use mysql and I am still learning it, in the meantime, shall be a good option the one to overwrite the df every time the program finds out new articles?

Comment: Don't do that. What if you need to analyse previous data? Save the dataframe to file daywise i.e `<datetime>.xlsx`. Storage is cheap, scraping is costlier

Comment: Thank you @bigbounty. Gotcha. Do you have, by any chance, any resource to connect my web scraping program to a mysql database even if I am not proficiency with it?

Comment: You can use Google Cloud Platform cloudsql. GCP offers free 300$ for one yearr

Answer (score 3):

Can you please elaborate more about the Problem #1 ?

> For problem # 2. You can run it on Linux based VPS and schedule it using cronjobs or you can AWS Lambda function and if you are saving result inside an external database.

Comment: When I posted the question yesterday, the first row was the latest article within the website linked above (i.e. the most recent one). If you check the website today, there are 4 more brand news articles on the top. I would like to fetch information from the 4 new articles within the website (with "scrape_global_news" function) and store them on the top of the data frame. The ultimate scope is to order them from the most recent to the last recent article.

Answer (score 0):

You can Put up your script On windows server and Store your Data in any Db for Example Postgresql and then In windows server or any windows machine if you want to schedule your job you can schedule it on via task scheduler and set it run frequency as per your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You install the `schedule` library and update your function as often as you like. Then, deploy the code to a Docker container and let it run 24/7.